# What's the difference between HTTP session and web session?

Tags: spring, http, session, reactive-programming

I understand that a HTTP session is the idea to associate a state of a web application for different users which is done outside the protocol in software as HTTP is stateless.

I didn't notice before today that [some articles and manuals in the Spring universe are talking about a web session as well](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/why-is-session-state-management-so-hard-with-spring-session-it-doesnt-have-to-be). They make a connection to reactive webapps and streams, however I don't find anything on https://www.reactive-streams.org/ and the reactive manifesto and am thus uncertain that it's a reactive thing.

Since it's differentiated it has to be a thing, but is it a concrete technical concept or just another word for HTTP session? Does it exist outside of the Spring universe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HttpSession](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) comes from the Java EE servlet specification and is defined as:

> [...] a way to identify a user across more than one page request or visit to a Web site and to store information about that user.

A [WebSession](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/WebSession.html) is essentially the same thing but is used in the context of the [Spring WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html) which provides reactive programming support for web applications.

Note also the existence of the [Spring Session](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session) project providing transparent integration with these different kind of sessions.